# C#: recursively replace characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, recursion

I have a string `"abcdef"` I want to change recursively. If a character `cha` is found, all characters up to this should be replaced with another character, `chb`
Ex.
If `cha = 'd'`, the modified string becomes "xxxxef" (if `chb = 'x'`).
If `cha = 'g'`, the string shouldn't be changed.

This is what I've tried

```
string myString = "abcdef";
char[] str = myString.ToCharArray();
void FindInString(int p)
{
   if (p < str.Length-1)
   {
      if (str[p] != cha)
         FindInString(p + 1);
   }
   str[p] = chb;
}
```

What I don't understand about recursitivity is what's happening on it's way back, ie. how to write a condition for the line

```
str[p] = chb;
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion? I'd simply use a loop...

Comment: @atlaste sounds like homework... to learn recursion

Comment: just write `else if`

Comment: Right, in that case my answer is: use the debugger 'step into', 'step over' features.

Comment: what to you do with such a string: `abcdefgda` does it become `xxxxxxxxa` ?

Comment: You need a clearer definition of what is rquired, e.g. for multiple occurances: 'abcdefgoooguuug'. Also: Your recursive function will need to 'carry around' all the data it needs, i.e. current string, limiting character andr replacement.

Comment: If it's homework to learn recursion, the teacher should be punished in public. I couldn't think of a worst example

Comment: And what condition do you need? It's obvious that the first character will be rewritten as a last in this whole operation

Comment: Yes, know there are better solutions in C#, but the thing is I wan't to learn and understand recursion, and it's not, as suggested in other comments, a homework, so there's no need to hang a teacher either;)

Comment: Why not go for the standard fibonacci implementation with recursive methods?

Comment: Maybe try some permutations instead. IMO that's the best thing to learn recursion.

Comment: If the whole thing is not about characters but about strings then recursion makes at least a litttle bit of sense..

Comment: @AlfredNilsson I tried to answer your last question about the return statements. Have a look at the edit. may be it helps to elucidate the fog of recursive return statements.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the easiest way: That you want to tackle the first appearance of the `char cha` in the string.

The first thing about recursion: be clear when this recursive-call-charade has to end! So you need the right exit strategy.

```
string s = "abcdefg";
```

- you would stop if there is no match for `cha`

  `if (!s.Contains(cha))`
- you would stop if you have found your match

  `else if (s[index] == cha)`
- otherwise you would increase the index and repeat the call

Now the second thing is the `return` value. Your method is supposed to change a string and return it. So It would be good to let it do so. If you pass all the necessary parameters into the method, it becomes independent of variables outside of its scope. You need:

- the string s
- an index to index the position
- and the matching char
- and of course the fitting return value

  `public static string FindInString(string s, int index, char cha)`

For string manipulations a `StringBuilder` is a convenient tool. It allows you to change chars at certain positions like in an array which is not possible in strings because they are immutable.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

// change the char at index:
sb[index] = 'x';
```

Now the final step is of course the recursive call. You basically go one step further with your index and **call the method again in the `return` statement**

```
index++;
return FindInString(sb.ToString(), index, cha);
```

This should suffice to enable you to write this method as a recursive version.
Write a comment if you still need help.

EDIT:

> What I don't understand about recursitivity is what's happening on it's way back,

What one tries to do is to break the entire problem into smaller sub-problems that resemble the structure of the entire problem. Imagine that at each recursive step you solve a part-problem of the entire problem and leave the part-solution at this step. As you keep walking down the stairs of recursion you ask at each step "is the entire problem solved?" if not repeat yourself/problem-solving-procedure. When you reach the final step and the question is answered with yes, you turn around and collect the solutions backwards when you climb the stairs of return statements backwards. This is of course only metaphorical, but one  way to illustrate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to better explain as suggested by @Mong Zhu

1) Identify the position of `cha` in your `myString`

2) Create a substring of all the character after `cha` --> `stringAfterCha`

3) Add the right number of `chb` before the `stringAfterCha` --> The PadLeft method add to your string as many as `chb` (2nd argument) are needed to reach the length (1st argument)

```
var cha = 'd';
var chb = 'x';
var myString = "abcdef";
int positionOfChaInMyString = myString.IndexOf(cha) + 1;
string stringAfterCha = myString.Substring(positionOfChaInMyString);
string result = stringAfterCha.PadLeft(myString.Length, chb);
```

Comment: OP is trying to learn something. Beside the very valid point made by @Pikoh here is no description or explanation whatsoever... not the most helpful approach..

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see this as a good example of recursion, but maybe this code helps you. Basically, you must return a bool for the calling method to know if the seached character has been found. If it has been found, you change the character you are analyzing and return true also to the previous calling method.Of course, this can be probably optimized, and decide what to do if there are duplicated searched characters, but it is just an example. And BTW, i'd advise you to always debug step by step your code, that way you'll see how it is working.

```
static bool FindInString(int p)
{
    char cha = 'd';
    char chb = 'x';
    if (p < str.Length - 1)
    {
        if (str[p] != cha)
        {
            if (FindInString(p + 1))
            {
                str[p] = chb;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            str[p] = chb;
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

The example call:

```
str = myString.ToCharArray();
FindInString(0);
```